# How to suppress outputs from specific modules and hidden class methods in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, echo, stderr, linefeed, fasttext

This is how the code looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#encoding:utf-8
import requests, numpy, fasttext, os, sys
from itertools import product
from math import sqrt

en_model=fasttext.load_model(path='crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin')
```

The script is intended to train a classification model using some NLP techniques. Here is the problem.

The last line of the snippet, for some unknown reason, outputs an empty line to the stderr, even though it runs without error. Is there any way to suppress it from the calling module, or do I have to hack into the fasttext module to know which line is causing this? In general, is there any way to suppress any stdout or stderr echo within a code snippet, specifically when I know that they are caused by modules being imported rather than what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

You can check contextlib.redirect_stdout and contextlib.redirect_stderr

Sample:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from contextlib import redirect_stderr
import os


def cache_stdouterr(func):
    def wrapper():
        with open(os.devnull,"w") as f:
            with redirect_stdout(f):
                with redirect_stderr(f):
                    func()
    return wrapper


@cache_stdouterr
def noprint():
    print("notprinted")

def toprint():
    print("shouldbeprinted")

toprint()
noprint()
```

---

```
# python3 test_redirect.py
shouldbeprinted
```

This is the generic solution. For your specific problem , you can try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#encoding:utf-8
import requests, numpy, fasttext, os, sys
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr
from itertools import product
from math import sqrt

with redirect_stderr(open(os.devnull,"w")):
    en_model=fasttext.load_model(path='crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin')
```